Get Average of Top 3 in a Summarized Table in Power Bi
I'm new to Power Bi and I'm facing a problem. I have Sales table in which there is column named Moony. The table is like this:



RowNumber
Moony
Volume




1
140309
123456


2
140309
15616


3
140210
565


4
140123
51


5
140202
123


6
140011
456


7
140202
123



I want to Group them by Moony and then get the average of top 3 Volumes Order by Moony desc. I tried the summarization of:
SUMMARIZE(Sales,Sales[Moony],"SalesVol",SUM(Sales[Volume]))

What can I try next?

Try this:
 Average of top3 = 
AVERAGEX(
    TOPN(3,
        SUMMARIZE(Sales,Sales[Moony],"@SalesVol",SUM(Sales[Volume])), 
        [Moony], 
        DESC
        ),
    [@SalesVol]
)


Thank you for your answer. But I wanted my summarized table to be sorted by moony and not by my aggregated column. I tried changing your [@SalesVol] with my Sales[Moony], but It returns sum of the whole data!

What is your expected output for the sample data you have provided?

I've updated the answer for you to try
